# Read lines from text file based on last match of particular string using groovy or shell script

Tags: shell, groovy, sh

I have a text file from which I need to read the lines based on last matching condition. e.g read all the line till the end of file after last occurrence of specific `word` or `string`.

Sample file:

```
2016 Jun 01 13:48:46:590 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300006 Engine COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet terminating 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:692 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:702 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:48:46:590 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300006 Engine COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet terminating 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:692 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:702 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:710 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:711 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: amd64 Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64  
2016 Jun 01 13:50:51:776 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300002 Engine COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet started
```

From above file I want to read all the lines after `last occurrence` of the string `COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet terminating`

Expected Output:

```
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:692 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
    2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:702 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
    2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:710 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01 
    2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:711 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: amd64 Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64  
    2016 Jun 01 13:50:51:776 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300002 Engine COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet started
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and the error you are getting?

Comment: I am trying this:  "tail -n "+$(($(grep -n 'COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet terminating' COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet.log | head -n 1 | cut -d ":" -f 1)+1))" COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet.log"  but it is returning from first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
def file = new File("file.txt")
def index = file.findLastIndexOf {it =~ "COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet terminating" }
def lines = file.readLines()
lines[(index+1)..(lines.size()-1)].each { println it }
```

Output :-

```
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:692 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:702 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:710 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:711 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: amd64 Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64  
2016 Jun 01 13:50:51:776 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300002 Engine COM PLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet started
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of language, there are two algorithms that can achieve this:

First:

```
initialise a temporary store (memory or temp file)
open input
while(read line) {
   if(line matches search pattern) {
        clear temp store
   }
   write line to temp store
}
copy temp store to output
```

Second:

```
open input
while(read line) {
   if(line matches search pattern) {
       store line number in variable
   }
}
close input
open input again
read until stored line number
read / write until end
```

The first option has the advantage that it works with piped input, where you cannot reopen the input at the start. But it has the disadvantage that you have to store output lines somewhere temporary until you reach the final line of input.

The second option has the advantage that it only ever holds one line of input in memory at a time. It has the disadvantage that it can never work with a source of input it can't re-open from the beginning.

You should be able to implement either of these fairly easily, either in Groovy or shell.

In shell you can cobble together a version of the second algorithm, if the input is a file:

```
 tail --lines=+$(grep -n pattern input.txt | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1) input.txt
```

Here we're using `grep -n` to find the matching lines (with line numbers), `tail -1` to pick the last one, `cut` to extract the line number, and `tail --lines=+n` to write those lines to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Since you posted this on groovy tag, I expect you can use groovy from the shell. I wrote the following script which works. Though it iterates through the file twice, it will work on a stream-y way and won't blow up your memory:

```
f = new File("sample.txt")

def lastIndex
f.eachLine { line, index ->
    if (line.contains("GenerateComplexitySheet terminating")) {
        lastIndex = index + 1
    }
}


new File("out.txt").with {
    write ""
    withWriter { writer ->
        f.eachLine { line, index ->
            if (index >= lastIndex) {
                writer.writeLine line
            }
        }
    }

    assert text == '''2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:692 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300001 Process Engine version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:702 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.11.0, build V62_hotfix017, 2015-9-24 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:710 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01 
2016 Jun 01 13:50:47:711 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: amd64 Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64  
2016 Jun 01 13:50:51:776 GMT +0200 BW.COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300002 Engine COMPLEXITY_CALCULATOR-GenerateComplexitySheet started
'''
}
```